# Copy git repo & change remote - what to call this?

Tags: git

I have a repo consisting of the first 10 well crafted commits for a new project.  This project will have a sibling where commits from this point onwards will diverge.  I have no need (right now) for this initial shared history to be in any way linked (it's frozen, complete as far as I'm concerned at this time). (I plan to rebuild both repos from scratch on an updated framework base in about 3 months).

The method I found myself doing naturally was simply to copy the folder, then change the remote to point to a new place.

What have I just done in git terminology?
This isn't a `clone`, a clone retains its origin remote.

One one level what I did seems almost too easy, on another, it's the obvious way to do it.  If I was explaining this to myself or someone else, how would I describe it?  If I said

> "I copied the repo then changed the   remote thus creating a new project"?

Would that make sense?

Is what I've done solid?  I'm fairly sure it is but open to suggestions.

Comment: In my opinion you are overthinking this. The sentence you propose is correct, and I don’t think there is any particular term for this. If any: “fork”.

Comment: It seems like an orphan branch and a new remote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is specific terminology for this. But I have a suggestion that might be usefull.

If it is a repository that you would like to use as a starting point for other projects then you could consider the option to make this a repository template on GitHub. This functionality is just released on GitHub. At your repo at settings you can mark the repo as repo template. After that you can use it as a template/starting point for new repo's.

More info here: [create repository template](https://github.blog/2019-06-06-generate-new-repositories-with-repository-templates/)